# Generate a directed graph with k inputs in j outputs and n nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to generate a directed graph using networkx in Python with the following characteristics: specified k inputs, j outputs, and n nodes. Ideally I would also be able to specify the connectivity of the graph through an additional parameter. I've played around with the [various graph generators](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.directed) in networkx, but I can't seem to find one that fits this specific description. The closest I've found is the `random_k_out_graph()` function, but I don't think that lets you specify the number of inputs as well. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work okay, generating various degrees of connectivity and specifying the number of inputs and outputs to both be 1:

```
def gen_degree_distribution(poisson_par, number_nodes):
    ### generate degree distribution
    in_degree = poisson.rvs(mu=poisson_par, size=number_nodes) + 1 # added one because we don't want any additional zero nodes
    in_degree_zero = np.insert(in_degree, 0, 0) # add a zero to the first in degree to say there is one seminal node
    out_degree_zero = np.insert(random.sample(in_degree.tolist(), 
                                              len(in_degree)), 
                                len(in_degree), 0)# add a zero to the last node to say there is one exit node
    return [in_degree_zero, out_degree_zero]

degree_out = gen_degree_distribution(1, number_nodes = 20)
in_degree_zero = degree_out[0]
out_degree_zero = degree_out[1]

D = nx.directed_havel_hakimi_graph(in_deg_sequence=in_degree_zero, 
                                   out_deg_sequence = out_degree_zero)

pos = nx.spring_layout(D)  # Positions of the nodes
nx.draw(D, pos, with_labels = True, arrows = True)
plt.show()
```